# How to load a value from . properties file in Cucumber-jvm step class

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration, cucumber-jvm

I have written a cucumber integration tests and it is running ok.

And then i wanted some class variables from the step.java to get their values from .properties values

```
public class cucumberStepClass { 
    @Value("${value.from.propertiesfile}")
    private String variable
//rest of integration test
}
```

Does anyone know how can i inject those values so my test can use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled integration with spring dependency injection? You need to add the `cucumber-spring` dependency for that. See https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/state/#spring

Comment: I guess reference moved to https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/state/#spring

Answer (score 2):

To add my two cents to the first answer: remember to annotate the class with `@SpringBootTest` and `@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")`. And the properties file should be `.properties` extension or `.xml`. `.yml` cannot be loaded.